# Refactor two methods in one (generics?)

Tags: c#, winforms, generics

I've got two methods for two different controls, to do same action:

```
public void DisplayTextForLabel<T>(Label pControl, string pText)
{
   pControl.Text = pText;
}
public void DisplayTextForLinkLabel<T>(LinkLabel pControl, string pText)
{
   pControl.Text = pText;
}
```

Is there any way to do that in one method, like:

```
public void DisplayTextForControl<T>(T pControl, string pText)
{
   pControl.Text = pText;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No Need to add generics

Try:

```
public void DisplayTextForControl(Control pControl, string pText)
{
   pControl.Text = pText;
}
```

> if you want to perform some action on control of particular type then you can always cast and check for it

EG:

```
public void DisplayTextForControl(Control pControl, string pText)
{
    pControl.Text = pText;

    if(pControl is LinkLabel llbl)
    {
         //Perform link label related actions
    }
    else if(pControl is Label lbl)
    {
         //Perform label related actions
    }
}
```

As per OP req.
You can try changing type to `RepositoryItemLookUpEditBase`

Answer (score 0):

You still don't need a generic method. A simple extension method will do.

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void SetText(this DevExpress.ExtraEdtiors.BaseControl ctl, string text)
    {
        ctl.Text = text;
    }
}

xbutton.SetText("Hello");
xlabel.SetText("Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to do it with generics you need to find a common ancestor of the two types e.g `control`. So something like...

```
public T SetControlText<T>(T control, string text) where T : Control
{
    control.Text = text;
    return control;
}
```

I'm not sure why you need generics in this instance though.